# Windows Service throwing MessageSecurityException

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, windows-services, wcf-security

We have a Windows Service that makes a WCF service call. Normally, it works fine. However, occasionally when we restart the Windows Service, a `MessageSecurityException` is thrown and everything goes to toss and it is thrown again repeatedly thereafter.

One solution we found is setting `AllowedImpersonationLevel` to "Impersonation". However, we don't use any impersonation. Also, it is a random issue and not always reproducible. Hence, this solution would be irrelevant.

Any light that someone can shed on this would be highly appreciated.

The stack trace of the error message:

> 2010-12-24 23:18:42,581 [3] ERROR
>   [DataSync] – An error occured during
>   Data Sync [(null)]
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   ‘Negotiate’. The authentication header
>   received from the server was
>   ‘Negotiate,NTLM’. ->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized. at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) —End of inner exception stack
>   trace --
>
> Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response,
>   WebException responseException,
>   HttpChannelFactory factory) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response,
>   HttpChannelFactory factory,
>   WebException responseException,
>   ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Comment: Is opposite WCF service hosted in IIS? if yes, then check user logged for failure requests in IIS logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an environment Issue. The machine couldn't connect to Domain controller, and hence failed to perform authentication, which caused this intermittent issue.